# How to use Stretch Icon to fill a panel

Tags: java, swing

I have a link explaining Stretch Icon and it provides the code https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/

I really tried to understand it and tried several time to implement it but with no success. 
I am facing this problem :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4SlO.png]

I want the green part (grass) to fill the Jpanel East.

So, can someone please explain to me how to use the StretchIcon class.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You might also like to provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: I'd imagine something along the lines of `add(new JLabel(new StretchIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/farmer.png"))), BorderLayout.EAST);`

Comment: I tried it out but it didn't add the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for the `StretchIcon` is to proportionally scale the image. Since the size of the "east" area is not in the same ratio as your image this won't work.

Instead you want the Icon to be scaled to fill the entire area. So you would use something like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new StretchIcon("...", false) );
label.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 1) );
add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Note you need to give the "preferred width" hint so the `BorderLayout` will know how much space to reserve on the east side of your panel.

Also, note it is better to use a larger image and scale it smaller so you don't get the pixilation.

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer but the whole idea was that I didn't want to use the setPreferredSize as the Frame can be opened on different monitors. So I can make it fit in one monitor but when I pass it to the larger one. It doesn't automatically fill

Comment: @Samer34, that is the way `BorderLayout` works. The "east" and "west" areas are a fixed width.  All the extra space goes to the center. The `StretchIcon` will fill properly when added to the `CENTER` of the BorderLayout. If you want all the areas to resize dynamically then you need to use a different layout manager. The problem is not the `StretchIcon`, the problem is your layout manager. Your question about how to use the `StretchIcon` has been answered. Determining the appropriate size for the label is a different issue based on your special requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now